# Can conda be configured to use a private pypi repo?

Tags: python, pip, conda, artifactory, pypi

I have users that create both conda and pip packages- I have no control over this

I use artifactory to host private conda and pip repos, for example this is how a private pip repo works:  https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/PyPI+Repositories

Sometimes there is a private pip package a conda environment or package needs. How can I configure conda to get my private pip packages from my private repo?

I haven't found documentation on this. I would like for this to be transparent for users as much as possible- so they set up their config once and in their conda environment they can easily specify a private pip package and it just works

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Conda won't search PyPI or alternative `pip`-compatible indexes automatically, but one can still use the `--index-url` or `--extra-index-url` flags when using `pip install`.  E.g.,

#### Ad Hoc Installation

```
# activate environment
conda activate foo

# ensure it has `pip` installed
conda list pip

# install with `pip`
pip install --extra-index-url http://localhost:8888 bar
```

#### YAML-based environments

**foo.yaml**

```
name: foo
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python
  - pip
  - pip:
    - --extra-index-url http://localhost:8888
    - bar
```

**Environment creation**

```
conda env create -f foo.yaml
```

Comment: But it will read my .pypirc to get username and password right? Otherwise how does it authenticate to the private repo? Do I have to manually pip install or will conda of fetch my creds from pypirc during a conda install/create/update/etc?

Comment: @red888 [as per docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#basic-authentication-credentials), it looks like you can use a `.netrc` file, keyring, or simply put the credentials in the URL.

Comment: Interesting that does not appear in the jfrog docs for configuring a private pypi repo. So for conda I would need to use netrc because it ignores pypirc?

Comment: @red888 not sure. TBH, I've never used a `.pypirc`; [docs seem to indicate](https://packaging.python.org/specifications/pypirc/) that it is only for *uploading to repositories*, in which case it's not Conda ignoring it, but it's `pip` that doesn't use it.

Comment: how do I specify `--extra-index-url` in a meta.yaml?

Comment: @red888 maybe I misunderstood. Conda builds of packages cannot depend on Pip-installed packages.