# How to specify pip --extra-index-url in environment.yml?

Tags: python, pip, conda

Conda can create an `environment.yml` that specifies both conda packages & pip packages.
The problem is, I want to specify a pip package (`torch==1.12.1+cu116`), that is only available in the following index: https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu116.

How can I specify this in the environment.yml?
Or at the very least, when running `conda env create -f environment.yml`, I would like to specify the extra index for pip.

Comment: That package is also available to be installed through conda

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This configuration should work, see the [`advanced-pip-example`](https://github.com/conda/conda/tree/main/tests/env/support/advanced-pip/environment.yml) for other options.

```yaml
name: foo
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python
  - pip
  - pip:
    - --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu116
    - torch==1.12.1+cu116
```

*See also*

- [Combining conda environment.yml with pip requirements.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35245401)
- [Can conda be configured to use a private pypi repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65383467)

Comment: Is it possible to set the extra-index-url in the .condarc file instead?